# Probability that diagonal of a rectangle is less than a given value $a$

Tags: probability

A rectangle is drawn so that none of its sides has length greater than $a$. All lengths lesser than $a$ are equally likely. The chance that the rectangle has its diagonal greater than $a$ is -------

The question, in my view basically demands the following approach ---

Let $x$ and $ y$ be the sides of the rectangle. Then according to question $x^2+y^2  < a^2$.

In my view both $a$ and $ x,y$ should have equal opportunity of becoming greater than each other. So we can proceed to find out where $x^2+y^2  =a^2$ is satisfied and then subtract it from the total ways in which $ x,y$ can be chosen. We then divide the previous result by 2 and that should give us the total number of favourable outcomes. However I am not getting the correct answer.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalently:

> Pick a random point in a square of side length $a$. What is the probability that the point is outtside the circle of radius $a$ around the lower left corner of the square?

This equivalent problem can be answered by comparing the area of the part of the square outside the circle with the area of the full square.

Comment: I have one confusion.the problem you stated is easy to solve in just one line,however how can you correlate the two differently looking problems.